# How to set CAMERA permission in order to pass regular test?

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

It is a very strange situation. I am working with `camera2` API and there is a regular method to open the camera.

```
manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
```

this method is requiring to make test, this one

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
            PackageManager.
        return;
    }
```

it is simple test to deduce if there was declared `CAMERA` permission in manifest or not.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

i have this permission in my manifest file and if i am uploading this app to *Samsung S5* it is work properly without problem, but if i am uploading this app to chinese device, mistake is happen. Don't pass the test and eventually don't open the camera...

Maybe should i set permission dynamically?

And one more thing, i have tryed call method to open the camera inside test, this way

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) !=
            PackageManager.
        manager.openCamera(mCameraId, mStateCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
        return;
    }
```

but get this mistake

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.android.camera2basic, PID: 29649 Theme: themes:{} java.lang.SecurityException: Lacking privileges to access camera service at android.hardware.camera2.utils.CameraBinderDecorator.throwOnError(CameraBinderDecorator.java:108) at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim.connectBinderShim(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:336) at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCameraDeviceUserAsync(CameraManager.java:327) at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.openCamera(CameraManager.java:457) at com.example.android.camera2basic.activities.CameraActivity.openCamera(CameraActivity.java:919)

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

On **API level 23+** you need to request permissions at runtime (even if you have them declared in your Manifest).

You should do something like this:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},
    CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

To process the result you need to override `onRequestPermissionsResult()` in your `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // permission granted
            // you can do your Camera related stuff
        } else {
            // permission denied
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) on runtime permissions.